# How to keep some space between tables in a row in knitr::kable?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

I use the following code from `bookdown` package [tutorial](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kable.html) in R markdown file:

````
```{r}
d1 <- head(cars, 3)
d2 <- head(mtcars[, 1:3], 5)
knitr::kable(
  list(d1, d2),
  caption = 'Two tables placed side by side.',
  booktabs = TRUE, valign = 't'
)
```
````

Unlike the book, the code returns the result without space between two tables, like so.

[image]

In some questions I see the solutions with `cat()` function and some `html` injections.

(Also we need to set the option `results = 'asis'`)

I wonder is there a more elegant and simple way to set some space between tables and preserve default html formatting at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not willing to do some tweaking using HTML/CSS, layout functions such as `fluidRow()` and `column()` from the *Shiny* package might help:

````r
```{r, echo=F}
library(kableExtra)
library(shiny)

d2 <- head(mtcars[, 1:3], 5) %>% kable() %>% kable_styling()

fluidRow(
    column(2, HTML(d2), offset = 2),
    column(2, HTML(d2), offset = 2),
)
fluidRow(align = "center", column(12, "Figure 1: Two tables side by side"))
```
````

[image]